# Why can't my iMac reach beyond my LAN?

Tags: network

I set up my LAN about a year ago and have had no problems with it previously.  I use Viasat for a satellite connection.  (Cable won't service this place.)  The connection comes in from the dish and connects to the Viasat router.  From there, it goes to a Soekris dox running an older version of pfSense.  This box has been running stably for this past year.  (And, yes, I'll be updating it soon.)  On the LAN side of this firewall is the house LAN, with a DISH TV Hopper and Joey, two MacMinis and two iMacs.  (Maybe a printer or two as well.)

Tonight we came home and the clock on the stove and microwave were blinking 12:00 and the computers were off.  Power failure.  We have a standby generator that is tested weekly, but we don't know if power was off long enough for the generator to kick on or not.  We just know we got home and could tell there had been a power failure.

So we set the clocks, make sure the DISH Hopper is working (and it's recording a program and doing fine).  Then my wife boots her iMac.  It connects to the internet without problem.  I boot one MacMini before I go upstairs, then I boot my iMac.

My wife's iMac connects to the internet.  My Mac Mini connects.  The DISH Hopper connects.  They have no problem reaching anything they need to.  When I turn on wifi for my iPad and go through the LAN wifi, I can connect to the internet without trouble.  (The iPad goes through an Airport Time Capsule hub, then through the firewall, then through the Viasat router.  In fact, everything in the house goes through the firewall, then the Viasat router.)

So I've tested everything in the house and it all connects to the internet without a problem.  (And, other than the iPad, they all connect, through hardwired ethernet cables, to a switch that has a hardwired connection to the firewall, which has a wired connection to the Viasat router and, from there, it's coax to the Viasat dish.)

Up until this power outage, the iMac in question never had trouble connecting to the internet.  The only thing that's different now is that last night I installed Mojave on this computer, but it worked fine when I rebooted it.  Now, it can connect to or see everything on my LAN, but nothing beyond the Viasat Router.

How is it this one iMac can't see anything beyond the LAN when it's never been a problem before and all the other systems on the LAN can see the entire internet?  And, of course, what can I do to fix it?

Comment: did you try to reset the wifi connection

Comment: Hi Tango, generally the best way to check for connectivity would be to open a terminal and ping devices to see where you’re being prevented from connecting through your default gateway. Start perhaps by typing “ping 127.0.0.1” to make sure your iMac is network capable. Then ping another host on your LAN “ping MacMini’s-IP”. You can find another device’s IP by going to Settings>Network and click on the green network interface (Wifi, Ethernet, whichever). Next, try pinging the router / default gateway. You can find that on another Mac product in Network>Advanced>TCPIP. Let me know your results.

Comment: @Buscar웃: Good point.  I thought I had stated that all connections but the iPad were wired - I need to clarify that better.

Comment: @Tmanok: Yes, the first thing I did was ping - I could ping loopback, the firewall LAN port, the firewall WAN port, and the Viasat router, which is, technically, outside my LAN that is all behind my firewall, but uses LAN addressing on it's LAN connection.  (In other words, the Viasat router uses the 192.168.xxx.xxx address space on it's LAN connector - which goes to my firewall's WAN connector.

Comment: check your DNS settings and try to use google 8.8.8.8

Comment: @Tmanok: I did not use wifi with the iMac.  It's capable of pinging and communicating with every computer on the LAN, plus the firewall, plus the Viasat router.  It's just anything outside that area that it won't connect to.  I can ping LAN devices by host name or by the IP addresses assigned by the pfSense DHCP server.

Comment: @Buscar웃: Are you talking the DNS settings in the iMac, the firewall (which is also the DHCP server for the LAN), or the Viasat router?  The firewall serves as DNS for the LAN and uses 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 as external DNS servers.

Comment: So you can ping all the way to the Viasat router but not behond? Are you pinging IP addresses or names? If names, try IP instead (e.g. ping 8.8.8.8).

Comment: Also, please add a screenshot of the relevant network settings on your Mac (or at least confirm that you checked and they are still correct).

Comment: I can ping with addresses and names up to the outside of the firewall.  I don't have a name for the Viasat router.  Network settings are what they were back when they were still working.  The DNS for the iMac is the firewall, which is also the DHCP server for the LAN.  The firewall uses 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 for outside DNS.

Comment: You're using DHCP, has manual configuration on your iMac failed as well? We're all asking networking questions, after this I'm pretty sure an Apple user should probably step in and talk about reverting to a backup. You could also share Ethernet to WiFi on another Mac machine, Preferences>Sharing>Internet. Select the appropriate from and to settings and try to connect your iMac to the shared wifi of another Mac. If that allows you to connect to the internet then your iMac has some sort of improper config (best guess) with its ethernet or wifi adapter for your network.

Comment: Okay, hand configured the DNS settings on the iMac and that's making it work.  So I'm thinking maybe the firewall DNS isn't forwarding requests as it should - at least one other system has hand configured DNS to include 8.8.8.8 and it's working.  I'll have to check my wife's iMac when she'll let me near it.  (She doesn't like anyone touching her computer.)